# RecylcerView in a Navigation Drawer Fragment not able to detect touch events

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, drawer, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to implement a Navigation drawer that uses a RecyclerView within a Fragment. Everything works fine except detecting the touch events. None of the touches are detected, neither in the RecyclerView touch listener nor the ViewHolder's touch listener.

I know that this approach might be outdated compared to using NavigationView from the new material design guidelines but I'd still like to know what I'm doing wrong here.

All help appreciated!

DrawerFragment:

```
public class DrawerFragment extends Fragment {

private DrawerAdapter mDrawerAdapter;
private RecyclerView mDrawerList;
private FragmentDrawerListener mDrawerListener;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private Context mContext;
private View mContainerView;

public DrawerFragment(){

}

public interface FragmentDrawerListener {
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position);
}

public void setDrawerListener(FragmentDrawerListener listener) {
    this.mDrawerListener = listener;
}

private List<DrawerItem> getDrawerItems(){
    List<DrawerItem> drawerItems = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] titles = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
    TypedArray icons = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        DrawerItem drawerItem = new DrawerItem(titles[i],icons.getResourceId(i, -1));
        drawerItems.add(drawerItem);
    }

    return drawerItems;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = getActivity();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_layout,container,false);

    mDrawerList = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
    mDrawerAdapter = new DrawerAdapter(getActivity(),getDrawerItems());
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mDrawerAdapter);
    mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mDrawerList.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), mDrawerList,new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            mDrawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mContainerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));

    return layout;
}


public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
    mContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });
}

public static interface ClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view, int position);
    public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}


static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
}
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DrawerFragment.FragmentDrawerListener {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private DrawerFragment mDrawerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initToolbar();
    initDrawer();
}

private void initToolbar() {
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}

private void initDrawer() {
    mDrawerFragment = (DrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    mDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    mDrawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    Log.i(TAG,"Stuff selected!");
}
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class DrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrawerAdapter.DrawerItemHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<DrawerItem> mDrawerItems;

public DrawerAdapter(Context context, List<DrawerItem> drawerItems) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mDrawerItems = drawerItems;
}

@Override
public DrawerItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.nav_item,parent,false);
    DrawerItemHolder drawerItemHolder = new DrawerItemHolder(view);
    return drawerItemHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DrawerItemHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTitle.setText(mDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.mIcon.setImageResource(mDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDrawerItems.size();
}

static class DrawerItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView mTitle;
    ImageView mIcon;

    public DrawerItemHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        mIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    }
}

}
```

Layout file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.raicky.example.ui.fragments.DrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/drawer_layout"
    tools:layout="@layout/drawer_layout" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```